# Typescript 2.1.5 Function calls are not supported

Tags: angular, typescript2.1

I have the following ngrx reducer function

```
export const raceReducer: ActionReducer<IRace> = ( state: IRace = new Race(), action?: Action ) => {
  switch ( action.type ) {

    case RaceActions.ADD_OLP:
      return ngrxStateUpdater( state, action )

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Running the application gives the following error:

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.
>   Function calls are not s upported. Consider replacing the function or
>   lambda with a reference to an exported fun ction (position 40:50 in
>   the original .ts file), resolving symbol raceReducer in J:/wor
>   kspace/angular2/ts/epimss/src/app/registration/race/race.ngrx-store.ts,
>   resolving symbo l AppModule in
>   J:/workspace/angular2/ts/epimss/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving
>   symbol AppModule in
>   J:/workspace/angular2/ts/epimss/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving
>   symbol Ap pModule in
>   J:/workspace/angular2/ts/epimss/src/app/app.module.ts

The function referred to is the

```
( state: IRace = new Race(), action?: Action )
```

Why is this and what is the solution. I thinks this should be legitimate typescript2.1.5 code, but it does not seem that way.

Thanks

Comment: Where and how are you using `raceReducer`?

Comment: The reducer is used as part of @ngrx/store. It is used to add an Action to update the state in the store. The following is the app.module : imports: [StoreModule.provideStore( {race: raceReducer} )]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AoT needs to statically analyze some code and can't analyze function invocations.

For more details about the limitations of AoT see https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter#aot--donts

For a discussion see this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11262

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be non trivial and as for `ngrx` looks like the answer is to use angular's `InjectionToken` to be AoT compatible. To be compliant with SO I'm shamelessly copying the solution from

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/306

`app.module.ts`:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store'

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'
import { reducers, reducerToken, reducerProvider } from './reducers';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducerToken),
  ],
  providers: [reducerProvider],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`reducers.ts`:

```js
import { ActionReducerMap, combineReducers } from '@ngrx/store'

import * as fromApp from './appReducers'
import * as fromNested from './nestedReducers'
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export interface IState {
    app: {
        a: fromApp.IState,
        b: fromNested.IState,
    }
}

export const reducers = combineReducers({
    a: fromApp.reducer,
    b: fromNested.reducer,
});

export const reducerToken = new InjectionToken<ActionReducerMap<IState>>('Reducers');

export function getReducers() {
    return {
      app: reducers,
    };
}

export const reducerProvider = [
    { provide: reducerToken, useFactory: getReducers }
];
```