# Error encountered resolving symbols statically

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I have an Angular4 application using ngrx. I created a undo higher-order reducer as documented [on the redux website](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ImplementingUndoHistory.html).

Unfortunately I am having issues with Ahead of Time (AoT) compilation when I apply this function in my root.reducers.ts file, and get this error

`ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'undoable', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol rootReducer`

The code works perfectly when AoT is turned off or after a file is modified, in which case just in time compilation is used.

I tried using [ngrx-undo](https://github.com/brechtbilliet/ngrx-undo) previously, but it didn't seem to work, which is why I rolled my own solution.

I've tried looking at other stackoverflow posts and searching google, but the majority of the other issues seem to be with 3rd party libraries or custom components, which aren't relevant in this case.

I know that I can fix the issue by removing the higher order reducer and converting cartReducer to be undoable directly, but that isn't desirable since we would have a lot of code duplication if we make any of the other reducers undoable.

How can I resolve this error? Preferably without removing AoT compilation, since that will be needed once we hit production.

## Code:

[See Gist for complete code](https://gist.github.com/WhiteAbeLincoln/d2f28b8bb6c621fd5fa82d987bcbfff9)

### root.reducers.ts

```ts
import { sessionReducer } from './reducers/session.reducers';
import { cartReducer } from './reducers/cart.reducer';
import { undoable } from './reducers/undo.reducer';
import { paymentReducer } from './reducers/payment.reducer';
import { accountReducer } from './reducers/account.reducer';
import { productReducer } from './reducers/product.reducer';
import { errorReducer } from './reducers/error.reducer';

export const rootReducer = {
  session: sessionReducer,
  cart: undoable(cartReducer),
  payment: paymentReducer,
  account: accountReducer,
  product: productReducer,
  error: errorReducer
};
```

Comment: Hi ! I know it's been a while, but I'm also struggling on the reducers with AOT. To me, this looks like you're not combining the reducers before giving it to the StoreModule... So it can't resolve statically the several reducers. To be fair, it's just an idea, nothing verified =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I abstracted out most of the undo reducer code into separate functions, and returned a function that built a specific reducer. This seemed to fix the issue

in cart.reducer.ts

```
const initialState: UndoState<CartState> = buildInitialState(initialCartState);
export function undoableCartReducer(state = initialState, action): UndoState<CartState> {
    return handleAction(state, action, cartReducer);
}
```

in undo.reducer.ts

```
export function buildInitialState<S>(state: S): UndoState<S> {
    return {
        past: [],
        present: state,
        future: []
    };
}

export function delegate<S>(state: UndoState<S>, action, reducer: ActionReducer<S>): UndoState<S> {
    const {past, present, future} = state;
    const newPresent = reducer(present, action);
    if (present === newPresent) {
       return state;
    }
    return {
        past: [...past, present],
        present: newPresent,
        future: []
    };
}

export function handleAction<S>(state: UndoState<S>, action, reducer: ActionReducer<S>): UndoState<S> {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'UNDO':
            return undo(state);
        case 'REDO':
            return redo(state);
        default:
            return delegate(state, action, reducer);
    }
}
```

new root.reducers.ts

```
export const rootReducer = {
  session: sessionReducer,
  cart: undoableCartReducer,
  payment: paymentReducer,
  account: accountReducer,
  product: productReducer,
  error: errorReducer
};
```

Comment: also look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47205420/3021889 for what seem to be the Angular way to deal with the AoT compatibility